# Ctrl+/ shortkey on a Thinkpad laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 (IntelliJ)?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ the shortkey `Ctrl+/` is by default configured for `Code -> Comment with Line comment` and when I select multi lines and click that option from the menu it works fine. But when I instead press `Ctrl+7` or `Ctrl+Shift+7` nothing happens.

On my Laptop keyboard the number 7 contains the forward slash `/`

Any ideas if I get that current assignment to work somehow?

Comment: Try adding a new keyboard shortcut in the IDE Keymap settings to Comment with Line comment action and press `Ctrl+Shift+7`. How is it recognized by the system, which shortcut is added?

Comment: Not sure I follow. You mean adding something different than the current/default `Ctrl+/` but NOT `Ctrl+Shift+7` and then see what happens when I press:`Ctrl+Shift+7`?

Comment: Yes, add the new keyboard shortcut and press the key you think produces `Ctrl+/` combination on your hardware, then see what's the actual key code reported by the system in the Keymap dialog.